# Setting up a dictionary with 1 list and a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have :

```
mydict = {}
days = ["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"]

temperatures =  [[16.0, 16.5, 17.2, 16.8, 18.8, 15.5, 21.4], [10.0, 9.2, 9.5, 10.0, 6.8, 9.4, 11.7], [12.857142857142858, 13.0, 13.442857142857145, 13.099999999999998, 12.157142857142858, 12.314285714285715, 14.428571428571429]]
```

I want `mydict` to look like this:

```
{"monday":(16.0 ,10.0 , 12.857142857142858), "tuesday":(16.5, 9.2, 13.0) ...
```

So what I want to is iterate over the list `days` and the 2d-array `temperatures`. Probably with a `for` loop but how do I set it up?

Answer (score 6):

Use a dict comprehension:

```
>>> {k : list(v) for k, v in zip(days, zip(*temperatures))}
{'monday': [16.0, 10.0, 12.857142857142858],
 'tuesday': [16.5, 9.2, 13.0],
 'friday': [18.8, 6.8, 12.157142857142858],
 'wednesday': [17.2, 9.5, 13.442857142857145],
 'thursday': [16.8, 10.0, 13.099999999999998],
 'sunday': [21.4, 11.7, 14.428571428571429],
 'saturday': [15.5, 9.4, 12.314285714285715]}
```

Use `tuple(v)` if you want tuples instead of lists.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dict(zip(days,map(tuple, temperatures)))
```

First make all temperatures arrays tuples, build a list of key-val entries and build a dictionary with this list, you will get:

```
{'tuesday': (10.0, 9.2, 9.5, 10.0, 6.8, 9.4, 11.7), 'wednesday': (12.857142857142858,    13.0, 13.442857142857145, 13.099999999999998, 12.157142857142858, 12.314285714285715, 14.428571428571429), 'monday': (16.0, 16.5, 17.2, 16.8, 18.8, 15.5, 21.4)}
```

Comment: You could replace `lambda x: tuple(x)` with `tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

Just zip your two lists together. You'll need a nested for loop to get each day->temperature.

```
days = ["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"]

temperatures =  [[16.0, 16.5, 17.2, 16.8, 18.8, 15.5, 21.4], [10.0, 9.2, 9.5, 10.0, 6.8, 9.4, 11.7], [12.857142857142858, 13.0, 13.442857142857145, 13.099999999999998, 12.157142857142858, 12.314285714285715, 14.428571428571429]]

for day, temps in zip(days,temperatures):
    for temp in temps:
        print("On %s the temperature was %f" %(day,temp,))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe, this is the shortest possible way:

```
dict(zip(days, zip(*temperatures)))
```

`zip(*temperatures)` will create a list of tuples `[(16.0, 10.0, 12.857142857142858), ...]`, then another `zip` pairs those tuples with keys and, finally, `dict` accepts a sequence of `(key, value)` couples.